# Android to PHP API Security

Tags: php, android, security, api, authentication

I have an API written in PHP that works by receiving HTTP POST requests, the API will then process the request and output some XML.

I have an Android application that is communicating with this API successfully.

My question is how do I make this secure?
I was looking into using OAuth, but for PHP it uses a library that is not available to me.
Plus as the API is not public and only to be used by external applications created by myself, this seems a bit overkill.

What other suggestions would you recommend? I was looking at sending an API key/signature along with the POST request.

Comment: Did you ever decide how to best implement this?

Answer (score 0):

It should be done the same way you make javascript calls secure. You use sessions. You should be able to send and receive headers, why not accept cookie-like data? At least `session_id`. Securing with SSL for open wifi hotspots would also be very beneficial if you use symmetric authentication.

OAuth has a different purpose - its when your website starts to host third party applications that users want to use without giving this app own password.